# how to find all the combinations of team possible using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, combinatorics

This is the screenshot of the dataset. Using this dataset I need to find all the possible combinations of 8 players whose score will be less than 100.
There are 2 teams players included in this dataset.
So the new team should either contain 3:4 or 4:4 ratio of players from the old teams.
And there must be at least one player from each position

[image: dataset]

**Below is the code I have tried.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import random
import itertools
from itertools import product

"""Importing dataset"""

dataset = pd.read_excel("NBA_0.xlsx")
print (dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset) 
df[['Player', 'Postion']]

"""Label Encoding"""

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Postion'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(dataset['Postion'])
df['Team'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(dataset['Team'])
df[['Player', 'Postion', 'Team']]

"""Select one player from each position"""

df_PG_0 = df[(df['Postion'] == 0) & (df['Team'] == 0)]
df_PG_0.sample()

df_PG_1 = df[(df['Postion'] == 0) & (df['Team'] == 1)]
df_PG_1.sample()

df_SG_0 = df[(df['Postion'] == 1) & (df['Team'] == 0)]
df_SG_0.sample()

df_SG_1 = df[(df['Postion'] == 1) & (df['Team'] == 1)]
df_SG_1.sample()

df_PF_0 = df[(df['Postion'] == 2) & (df['Team'] == 0)]
df_PF_0.sample(2)

df_PF_1 = df[(df['Postion'] == 2) & (df['Team'] == 1)]
df_PF_1.sample()

df_C_0 = df[(df['Postion'] == 3) & (df['Team'] == 0)]
df_C_0.sample()

df_C_1 = df[(df['Postion'] == 3) & (df['Team'] == 1)]
df_C_1.sample()

df_SF_0 = df[(df['Postion'] == 4) & (df['Team'] == 0)]
df_SF_0.sample()

df_SF_1 = df[(df['Postion'] == 4) & (df['Team'] == 1)]
df_SF_1.sample()

df_sample_H = pd.concat([df_PG_0, df_SG_0, df_SF_0, df_PF_0, df_C_0]).sample(3)
print(df_sample_H)

df_sample_L = pd.concat([df_PG_1, df_SG_1, df_SF_1, df_PF_1, df_C_1]).sample(5)
print(df_sample_L)

df_sample_team = pd.concat([df_sample_L, df_sample_H]).sample(8)
print(df_sample_team)

"""select 3:4 players from each team"""

df_sample = pd.concat([df_PG_0,df_PG_1, df_SG_0, df_SG_1, df_SF_0, df_SF_1, df_PF_0, df_PF_1, df_C_0, df_C_1]).sample(8)
print(df_sample)


"""Credit Score should be less than 100"""

df_value = df_sample_team.Credits.cumsum() 
print(df_value)
```

Using the above code I could get only one team at a time. How can I modify my code such that I will get all the possible teams who score less than 100.
There are 2 teams players included in this dataset.
So the new team should either contain 3:4 or 4:4 ratio of players from the old teams.
And there must be atleast one player from each position

Comment: couple questions...  what is the desired number of players on a team and how does that match up with your ratios?  What to you intend to do next with the result?  This could have thousands of outcomes...are you trying to optimize or "pick the best" in some way?  Are you intending to scale beyond just combining 2 teams?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 1):

To get a df of all the teams who scored less than 100 Points, let's name it `dfteams`

```
dfteams = df.loc[df['Points'] < 100, 'Team']
```

One can also create a new column based on the condition and assign a value 1/0 if the condition is satisfied or not

```
cond = (df['Points']<100)
df['New'] = np.where(cond, 1, 0)
```